# Is it alright to write a software creates a roster for a restaurant with JAVA language?

Tags: database

I need some advice on the project im working for fun during the summer. Say im writing a software that helps creating the roster base on the availiabilities of the staffs. I need some advice on how to implement these items below:

1. A database that holds the infomation of the staffs (ie.
   availiabilities, minimum hours, maximum hours).
2. The core of the software where the process of arranging staffs on a day base on the database.
3. A GUI that displays the final version of roster after step 2 above so it can be printed out by the manager.

Im thinking of using Java but not sure how i to implement and connect the database, the core and the GUI together? Can i do everything listed using Java?Can anyone please suggest me a solution or an article for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many different paths you could follow, depending on what your end goals are.

DO you want to learn Java or are you just trying to practice application development ?  I am assuming you are interested in an application that runs on the web.

For me, the best choices are either Java or PHP, but this is largely based on my own experiences. Others might argue that Python or Ruby would be a better to start.

For a Java based solution, you would use: Java JSPs with HTML for the front end (Javascript and JQuery optional); Java (Servlets) for the middle tier; JDBC, JPA, Spring, and/or Hybernate to connect to the DB; MySQL is a good candidate for the DB, but there are other options.

For a PHP based solution, you would use: PHP, HTML for the frond end (Javascript and JQuery optional); PHP for the middle tier (there are frameworks you coulse here as well); PHP to connect to the DB; MySQL is a good candidate for the DB, but there are other options.

If you dont know either, I think PHP is easier to setup and run for beginners, and is the basis for many open source and commercial web applications (e.g., WordPress); but Java is used for most large scale applications.

Comment: Hello TDWebDeb. Thank you for your answer. Im studying computer engineering and i have some experience on programming with Java. Id like to learn more about it. My goal is to write a software that can run as a desktop application (i may try to develope it on a website as you suggest once i have the basic application).

Comment: I see. For that scenario, I think everything still holds except for the front end component. You would probably use Java Swing or one of the Microsoft application languages instead of JSPs.  Good luck.